# Tag synonym request: [dependency-inversion] → [dip-principle]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Please add [dependency-inversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependency-inversion) as a synonym of [dip-principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dip-principle).
Both refer to the fifth of Robert Martin's SOLID principles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done; same principle as [the other request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380927).

[dependency-inversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependency-inversion) ← [dip-principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dip-principle)

This mapping avoids all potential confusion with "Density Independent Pixel", although I wasn't able to get approval from the Department of Redundancy Department.

---

Speaking of Density Independent Pixels, the [dip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dip) tag needs to be cleaned up. Several folks have used it to mean "DPI", a few are using it to mean "Dependency Inversion Principle", and [still others are using it in unknown ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092894/how-do-i-tell-if-a-cron-job-on-openshift-is-working-or-not). Since there's no [density-independent-pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/density-independent-pixel) tag requiring disambiguation, I renamed [dip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dip) to that. I'll get back to cleaning up [density-independent-pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/density-independent-pixel) when I get a chance, or others who have a few moments can pick up where I left off.