# Tag synonym request: [open-closed-principle] → [ocp]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Please add [open-closed-principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-closed-principle) as a synonym of [ocp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ocp). Both refer to the second of Robert Martin's SOLID principles.

Comment: Should point the other way if anything, i.e., towards the more explicit name.

Comment: The convention for the other principles seems to be towards the acronym, i.e. srp, lsp.

Comment: Then that convention is wrong, and should also be changed. TMA in TLA, too much RFC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, this is now done. Of course, I agree with Josh Caswell, that the tag synonym should point the other way, so the more descriptive tag name is the "master". Thus, it is implemented as:

[open-closed-principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-closed-principle) ← [ocp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ocp)

where the latter has been merged with the former, and a synonym has been created.

Should be live on a Stack Overflow near you momentarily (allow for caching effects).

To pre-empt your inevitable question: this proposal got downvoted because it's an *extremely* low-effort tag synonym request. There's a whole process for proposing these, but it basically boils down to just doing a bit of preliminary analysis yourself and presenting a more compelling justification. In this particular case, it happens to be a good idea, and I did the legwork myself.

Looking through all the questions that were originally tagged [ocp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ocp), two were not about the Open-Closed Principle in any form, shape, or fashion:

- [Openshift Origin htpasswd auth not working - unable to login to web console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575579/openshift-origin-htpasswd-auth-not-working-unable-to-login-to-web-console)
- [Which two are true about the Inventory directory in Oracle 11G?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53348249/which-two-are-true-about-the-inventory-directory-in-oracle-11g)

I have no idea why the tag was used on the first one. For the second one, they were trying to refer to the Oracle Certification Program, which should not have a tag here. I retagged both of them manually.

---

We should now have all of the five SOLID principles on solid ground:

- [open-closed-principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-closed-principle) ← [ocp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ocp)

- [dependency-inversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependency-inversion) ← [dip-principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dip-principle)

- [single-responsibility-principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-responsibility-principle) ← [single-responsibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-responsibility)
- [single-responsibility-principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-responsibility-principle) ← [srp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/srp)

- [liskov-substitution-principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liskov-substitution-principle) ← [liskov-substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liskov-substitution)
- [liskov-substitution-principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liskov-substitution-principle) ← [lsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lsp)

- [interface-segregation-principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interface-segregation-principle) ← [isp-principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isp-principle)

I avoided creating [dip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dip) and [isp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isp) tags as synonyms because of the overloaded meanings of these acronyms. Please let me know if there's anything else that needs to be done here.

Comment: Actually, my inevitable question is, can other SOLID principle synonyms be reversed to point at the more descriptive master? Specifically, the `srp` and `lsp` acronyms are currently masters. Consistency across the five principles would be nice.

Comment: Sure. I respect the need for consistency. [[tag:srp]] and [[tag:lsp]] are the only two in need of attention, @jaco?

Comment: The only SOLID tag remaining would be [isp-principle](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/isp-principle/info) but there is no `interface-segregation` tag to point at.

Comment: I can create tags, so that's done, too. Probably should have posted this all as one feature request. I'll update the answer with a summary.